# Docker Swarm Ports becomes non responsive

Tags: linux, nginx, docker, docker-swarm, docker-networking

I am running a swarm cluster with only 3 masters. I have a few ports exposed across various services in the swarm. And an Nginx service running in all 3 nodes acts as a reverse proxy.

When I start the stacks, all these ports are accessible and responding as expected. But after some time, some of these ports become non-responsive to some servers and the Nginx starts throwing 504 timeouts. (i.e) port 5000 is responding to requests from Master 1 but not from Master 2 and 3 and port 6000 is responding to requests from Master 1 and 3 but not from Master 2.

These are the output's of `nmap -Pn 172.17.0.1`

```
# Master 1
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp   open     ssh
80/tcp   open     http
443/tcp  open     https
5000/tcp open     upnp
6000/tcp open     mmcc
```

```
# Master 2
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp   open     ssh
80/tcp   open     http
443/tcp  open     https
5000/tcp filtered upnp
6000/tcp filtered mmcc
```

```
# Master 3
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp   open     ssh
80/tcp   open     http
443/tcp  open     https
5000/tcp filtered upnp
6000/tcp open     mmcc
```

The Output of `netstat -lnpt | grep 5000` (Same in all 3 nodes)

```
tcp6       0      0 :::5000                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

I am unable to figure out if this issue is something related to the docker swarm or Nginx or the host machine itself.
Any help in debugging this would be highly appreciated. I would be more than happy to share any more info if required.

Thanks in advance.